# when i am using solidity version 0.4.25 i was geting an error

Tags: solidity

i am trying to finish the solidity code in which it includes arithmatic operator '>=' it is throwing an error someone please help me with the error
the error is - 'expected ; but got <='

This is for a Smart Contract to check the draw between 3 people i have tried on different solidity versions but it throwing an error for -  int count <=

`

```
function isDraw() view public returns(bool){
    uint256 a = getplayerGuessNum(getPlayers()[0]);
    uint256 b = getplayerGuessNum(getPlayers()[1]);
    uint256 c = getplayerGuessNum(getPlayers()[2]);
    int count <= 3;
    if(a==b || a==c || b==c){
        return false;
        count++;
    }
    else{
        return true;
    }

}
```

`
The code above should check 3 times if there is draw between the a,b,c but i am getting an error @ int count <= 3

Comment: Of course you are getting an error there. What is `int count <= 3;` supposed to do?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to check three times you should put the whole block that you want to run three times in a loop (for, while).

Answer (score 0):

If what you want is to initialize count to 3 then change

```
int count <= 3;
```

to

```
int count = 3;
```

Anyway that line is wrong because after a variable declaration you should only end the line or use an assignment